# Shape drawable not working?

Tags: android, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="3dp"
    android:innerRadius="34dp">

    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>

</shape>
```

I want to create ring but nothing appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#ff0000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

using ring shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="15dp"
    android:thickness="10dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Cant we use just ring shape ?Why go for oval shape to make ring shape?

Comment: if u r using eclipse for development then ring shape will display a simple circle in preview please run in device & check it

Comment: u can refer this link for different ring shapes http://android-dev-examples.blogspot.in/2014/08/android-shape-ring.html

Comment: Can u please answer this one?its based on your answer

Comment: What is the purpose of [   android:useLevel="false"     ]  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this for ring shape with fill transparent. set this drawable to your control.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
  <corners android:radius="10dip" /> 
  <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="@color/white" /> 
  <size android:width="100dp" android:height="100dp" /> 
  <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" /> 
  </shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create ring from following code

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
        android:shape="oval">
      <corners android:radius="10dip" /> 
      <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#ffffff" /> 
      <size android:width="75dp" android:height="75dp" />  
      </shape>
```