# Unable to understand layer-list

Tags: android, layer-list, android-shape, android-shapedrawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#ff0000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#ff0000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

taken from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36003935/6007737

> How is it giving me a ring shape?

How layer-list works and What do top, right, bottom and left attributes of item tag do?

> Cant we just use ring shape ?Why go for oval shape to make ring shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A layer list is drawable, called sequence of other drawables with `<item>` tag.
Here from your question the first `<item>` is inner oval shape & top, bottom, right & left are insets given to that item (just same as padding). Try to give width & height to first  you can see inner oval shape with 4dp padding from outer oval.

Refer to this link for more detail about layer drawable http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html

Yes you can use ring shape to draw a ring like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="15dp"
    android:thickness="10dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="#ff0000" />

</shape>
```